# Java 8 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Serializable> to List<String>

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of Strings:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a1,a2", "b1,b2");
```

Then to convert everything in a list like: `"a1","a2","b1","b2"` wrote this:

```
List<String> ss1 = list.stream()
                       .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split(",")))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I had an error: *"Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<Serializable>` to `List<String>`"*. I handled the problem changing into this:

```
List<String> ss2 = list.stream()
                       .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Eclipse Neon suggests that the difference is in the `flatMap` return type. First `flatMap` returns a `List<Serializable>` second returns a `List<String>`.

But both `Stream.of()` and `Arrays.stream()` returns a `<T> Stream<T>` (Eclipse suggests that they both returns a `Stream<String>`).

And again, `Stream.of()` internally use (and returns the output of) `Arrays.stream()`. So, again, what's wrong in the first case?

Comment: `Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream()`...

Comment: Your code works on IntelliJ Idea 2016 with Java 1.8, maybe you should have a look at your IDE's settings.

Comment: @Andrea you're right, this problem happens only within Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @Boris the Spider: in the `flatMap` use case: `.flatMap(Pattern.compile(",")::splitAsStream)`…

Comment: @Holger indeed. And that would also guarantee than there are not multiple calls to `Pattern.compile` - which would be a problem for a lambda.

Comment: @Boris the Spider: well, it’s a corner case. If the pattern is as simple as `","`, the method `String.split` will go a fast path, not using the regex engine. Still, it implies creating and eagerly filling an array.

Comment: A note, the first snippet fails to compile on Eclipse Neon.2. But it works on Neon.1 and Mars.2... so it looks like there was an Eclipse regression here. [Bug already reported](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508834).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### This is an Eclipse bug

<sub>[Bug 508834](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508834), thanks to [@Tunaki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571839/java-8-differences-between-arrays-stream-and-stream-of/41571931#comment70355898_41571839)</sub>

---

Notice the method signatures:

```
//Stream.of
<T> Stream<T> of(T... values)
//Arrays.stream
<T> Stream<T> stream(T[] array)
```

Now, for `Arrays.stream` it is obvious that a call with an array of type `T` will return a `Stream<T>`. But with `Stream.of` should it return `Stream<T>` or `Stream<T[]>`? i.e. what is the type of the varags; are you passing your array are the first parameter (so the varargs are an array of arrays) or are you passing your array as *all* the parameters?

That's your issue.

Comment: Not sure this is the correct answer. If you look at source code of `Stream.of()` you'll see that internally uses `Arrays.stream()`. And both the static functions have the same return type.

Comment: @freedev it's a type inference thing is my point. Your `Stream` is asking a lot more from the type inference than a single chained method call. If you were to force a cast I imagine it would work.

Comment: Argh... I have tried using maven at command line and both the lines compile correctly. It is definitely a problem related to Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @freedev: `Stream.of` is a varargs method, hence, intended to be used when you have multiple arguments, whereas `Arrays.stream` is preferred when you have an existing array. Since inside the implementation code of `Stream.of(T...)` there is an existing array, delegating to `Arrays.stream` makes perfectly sense. Especially, as there will be no technical difference at the lowest level. Still, it’s recommended to use the right method at API/source code level.

Comment: Hi @Holger, I got your point but, at least for me, the interesting thing is understand why Eclipse has this type inference issue. I'm still looking for the parameter that has raised this strange behaviour.

Comment: @freedev: Note that you can write `Stream.<String[]>of(s.split(","))` to create a single-element Stream consisting of the `String[]` object whereas `Stream.<String>of(s.split(","))` will create a Stream of `String` instances having as much elements as the array. The type inference has to decide between these two cases and apparently, that Eclipse version did the wrong decision. In contrast, for `Arrays.stream(s.split(","))`, there is no such decision to make.

Comment: Yes, this is an Eclipse bug, a regression in Neon.2. This used to work with previous versions, [see my comment on the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571839/java-8-differences-between-arrays-stream-and-stream-of#comment70355898_41571839).